# Q: Sending Data to MongoDB using dotNet

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql, code-first

Is there a way to send data to MongoDB using dotNet (Code first approach)?

Comment: Is there an EF provider for MongoDB? You could check its docs? (If anything like the CosmosDB support, likely to be a lot of EF that works a little differently.)

Comment: check documentation https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found two approach:

[1]: https://cdata.com/kb/tech/mongodb-ado-codefirst.rst using EF6

[2]: using MongoDB.Driver